# How to get dictionary value of a key inside a loop in Django Template?

Tags: python, html, django, templates, jinja2

## views.py

```py
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    domains = Domain.objects.all()
    context['domains'] = domains

    domain_dict = {}
    # ..........
    # ..........some codes here for domain_dict dictionary
    print(domain_dict)
    context['domain_dict'] = domain_dict
    return render(request, self.response_template, context)
```

- Output after printing the `domain_dict`

> `{4: '', 3: '', 1: '', 5: '', 7: '', 2: '', 6: 'Are you a candidate for the engineering admission '}`

- Now the `domain_dict` is sent to `template` through **context**.

## templates.html

```html
<div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="tab-content">
        {% for domain in domains %}
            {% with domain_id=domain.id %} 
            <div class="tab-pane container p-0 {% if forloop.first %} active {% endif %}" id="services{{domain.id}}">
                <div class="img" style="background-image: url('static/counsellor/images/service-1.png');">
                </div>  
                <h3><a href="#">Name: {{domain.name}} ID: {{domain_id}}</a></h3>
                <p>{{domain_dict.6}}</p>
            </div>
            {% endwith %}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

> In the above template I use `<p>{{domain_dict.6}}</p>`. `domain_dict.6` to find the value of key `6`. It returns perfectly.
> Outputs: `Are you a candidate for the engineering admission.`

- But in the below

```html
<div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="tab-content">
        {% for domain in domains %}
            {% with domain_id=domain.id %} 
            <div class="tab-pane container p-0 {% if forloop.first %} active {% endif %}" id="services{{domain.id}}">
                <div class="img" style="background-image: url('static/counsellor/images/service-1.png');">
                </div>  
                <h3><a href="#">Name: {{domain.name}} ID: {{domain_id}}</a></h3>
                <p>{{domain_dict.domain_id}}</p>
            </div>
            {% endwith %}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

> In the above template I use `<p>{{domain_dict.domain_id}}</p>`. `domain_dict.domain_id` to find the value of key `domain_id`. It returns null. Here  `domain_id = 4,3,1,6,5,7,2`
> Outputs: `null`

### How can I return the value of a key of the dictionary here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've recently run into the same problem. Here is example of the solution.

Say, we have tuple

```
people = ('Vasya', 'Petya', 'Masha', 'Glasha')
```

and dictionary with their status:

```
st = {
    'Vasya': 'married',
    'Petya': 'divorced',
    'Masha': 'married',
    'Glasha': 'unmarried'
}
```

We transfer these to our template as context of corresponding view:

```
context['people'] = people
context['st'] = st
```

If we write in template

```
{% for person in people %}
    {{ person }} is {{ st.person }}
{% endfor %}
```

then it won't work. Well, 'person' will be displayed, but data from dictionary will not. [Because](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/language/#variables) :

> Note that **bar** in a template expression like {{ foo.bar }} will be
> interpreted as a literal string and not using the value of the
> variable **bar**, if one exists in the template context.

The solution of the problem is either to use another data structure or to use custom filter in the template. The idea of the latter is to add a filter to your dictionary in the template, which takes current value of *person* and returns corresponding value of the dictionary.
To do this,

1. create in the folder with your app new folder *templatetags*,
2. write the path to this new folder in *settings.py*,

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            ...,
            os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'your_app/templatetags'),
        ],
       ...
    }
```

3. inside the *templatetags* create new file, say, *filter.py* with our new filter called *dict_value*:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def dict_value(d, key):
    return d[key]
```

4. go back to your template and load newly created filter somewhere in first lines:

```
{% load filter %}
```

5. rewrite you template code like this:

```
{% for person in people %}
    {{ person }} is {{ st|dict_value:person }}
{% endfor %}
```

Now it works as needed.